Как расшифровать oid полученные через snmpwalk?
Я хочу настроить мониторинг принтеров через Zabbix. Попробовал получить данные по SNMP с одного принтера при помощи snmpwalk. Мне выдало кучу oid, и не понятно что за что отвечает. Читал что описание oid можно получить через mib файлы. Как это сделать? Можно ли сделать так чтобы при использовании snmpwalk сразу отображалось описание oid?

Значит, смотрите. Есть публичная база для принтеров: https://mibbrowser.online/mibdb_search.php?mib=Printer-MIB
Скачайте её как MIB
Эта база не сама по себе, а импортирует несколько других баз: SNMPv2-CONF, IF-MIB, SNMPv2-SMI, HOST-RESOURCES-MIB, IANA-CHARSET-MIB, SNMPv2-TC, IANA-PRINTER-MIB
Эти базы тоже скачайте:

https://mibbrowser.online/mibs/HOST-RESOURCES-MIB.mib
https://mibbrowser.online/mibs/IANA-CHARSET-MIB.mib
https://mibbrowser.online/mibs/IANA-PRINTER-MIB.mib
https://mibbrowser.online/mibs/IANAifType-MIB.mib
https://mibbrowser.online/mibs/IF-MIB.mib
https://mibbrowser.online/mibs/SNMPv2-CONF.mib
https://mibbrowser.online/mibs/SNMPv2-MIB.mib
https://mibbrowser.online/mibs/SNMPv2-SMI.mib
https://mibbrowser.online/mibs/SNMPv2-TC.mib

Сложите их все в одну папку и запустите snmpwalk:
snmpwalk <адрес-принтера> -v1 -c public -m Printer-MIB.mib -M <папка-с-MIB-ами>

Пример: я сложил все мибы в текущий каталог и опрашиваю домашний принтер
snmpwalk 192.168.1.128  -v1 -c public -m ./Printer-MIB.mib -M .

Результат (с сокращениями и моими комментариями):
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Canon MF633C/635C /P
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1602.4.7
SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0 = Timeticks: (448513) 1:14:45.13
...
# перечень интерфейсов
IF-MIB::ifNumber.0 = INTEGER: 4
...
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.4.20.1.1.127.0.0.1 = IpAddress: 127.0.0.1
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.4.20.1.1.192.168.1.128 = IpAddress: 192.168.1.128
...
# информация об устройстве
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemUptime.0 = Timeticks: (449022) 1:14:50.22
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemDate.0 = STRING: 2024-10-31,19:35:43.0
...
# Инфоомция о принтере
Printer-MIB::prtInputDefaultIndex.1 = INTEGER: 2
Printer-MIB::prtOutputDefaultIndex.1 = INTEGER: 1
...
Printer-MIB::prtInputType.1.1 = INTEGER: sheetFeedManual(5)
Printer-MIB::prtInputType.1.2 = INTEGER: sheetFeedAutoRemovableTray(3)
...
Printer-MIB::prtInputVendorName.1.1 = STRING: "Canon"
Printer-MIB::prtInputVendorName.1.2 = STRING: "Canon"
...
Printer-MIB::prtOutputType.1.1 = INTEGER: unRemovableBin(4)
Printer-MIB::prtOutputCapacityUnit.1.1 = INTEGER: sheets(8)
...
Printer-MIB::prtOutputPageDeliveryOrientation.1.1 = INTEGER: faceDown(4)
...

